SSL error when trying to import db using wp-cli and mariadb
Running wordpress with bedrock+docker using webdevops/php-apache:8.2-alpine and mariadb:10.4
Recently I am getting errors when trying to export/import the database through wp-cli.
Not sure what could have changed in the environment, have not made any changes to the db image or php/apache image.
Wordpress version: 6.7.1
wp-cli version: 2.11.0
Trying to export:
5cb38ad01152:/app# wp db export wp-backup.sql --allow-root
mysqldump: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use '/usr/bin/mariadb-dump' instead
mysqldump: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use '/usr/bin/mariadb-dump' instead
mysqldump: Got error: 2026: "TLS/SSL error: SSL is required, but the server does not support it" when trying to connect

This can be solved by appending --ssl=0
5cb38ad01152:/app# wp db export wp-backup.sql --allow-root --ssl=0
mysqldump: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use '/usr/bin/mariadb-dump' instead
mysqldump: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use '/usr/bin/mariadb-dump' instead
Success: Exported to 'wp-backup.sql'.

But this does not work for import:
5cb38ad01152:/app# wp db import wp-backup.sql --network --allow-root
Error: Failed to get current SQL modes. Reason: mysql: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use '/usr/bin/mariadb' instead
ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: SSL is required, but the server does not support it

5cb38ad01152:/app# wp db import wp-backup.sql --network --allow-root --ssl=0
Error: Failed to get current SQL modes. Reason: mysql: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use '/usr/bin/mariadb' instead
ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: SSL is required, but the server does not support it


Since the post ist nit about programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I would suggest asking for advice in the wordpress.org forum.

Uh oh. The differences between MySQL and MariaDB are escalating, and we're getting close to WordPress having to cope with them rather than treating the two DBMSs as identcal.

Looks like that should pass through. Ssl as a [client] MariaDb config option. Also 10.4 out of maintenance and you're using a newer MariaDb client than the database server causing this incompatibility.

thanks @danblack I have tried updating mariadb, now getting 'TLS/SSL error: self-signed certificate' instead.
it looks like passing extra arguments doesn't work for import.
Found a seemingly related issue in the wp-cli github:
https://github.com/wp-cli/db-command/issues/218

See this question
